# Generate skipable list based on chars

Tags: c#, string, list

I am very sure that there is a technical term for this problem, but unfortunately I do not know it.
I have an alphabetical charset and the requirement is to create the combination of all the chars with a maximum length

The idea is (sample):

- Generate a collection of A, AA, AAA, AAAA, AAAAA, AAAAAA
- Next: A, AB, ABA, ABAA, ABAAA
- Next A, AB, ABB, ABBA, ABBAA

The reason:
We have to query an API that delivers search results.

But if I don't get search hits from the API on AAA, I don't need to search for AAAA anymore, because it can't get search hits either. I can then move on to AAB.

The question:

My problem is that I'm not sure how the code has to be built to achieve this goal. I lack the structural approach.
I've already tried nested loops, but unfortunately I don't get the result.
I also used Combination Libraries, but they focus on other problems.

Many thanks for hints!

Comment: Could you be looking for the `yield` contextual keyword? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield
Gives you a chance to generate members of an `IEnumerable` through a method, dynamically.

Comment: So it could go up to all 26 letters in the alphabet?

Comment: Are you looking for help coming up with the list of all possible combinations or are you looking for help with the logic of how to skip a generation within the API call?

Comment: Yes, I know how to use `yield`, thanks. But my problem is how to generate the logic here.

Comment: It's very unclear what you have problem with... Obviously in your recursive solution you have something like `if (continueRecursion) recursiveCall() else return;` which should generate the list you want... so without actually seeing code it is not really possible to help...

Comment: The problem is that I lack the approach of how to achieve such a structure that is "breakable". I have to create a string that I can "skip" when I have no more hits.

I am very very advanced with C# - but I lack the mathematical approach here, so I achieve the corresponding structure of the loops. I can't create the string somehow, otherwise I can't skip the corresponding characters.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a particular data structure called a [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), but probably more specifically in your case, a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Trie data structures are commonly used in things like Autocomplete. With the image below, if someone typed "te", I can traverse the Trie and see what options would come after that (tea, ted, ten).

It looks like this would also fit your use case from what I can tell.

[image]

Comment: That could be an interesting approach. Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be a little dated, but a decent .NET-oriented article could be found here to see how something like this could work in practice - https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/20/text-pattern-search-trie-class-net.aspx